# Retrieve key from key in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a class `Foo` that has an instance string variable `id`.  I implemented the `__eq__` and `__hash__` magic methods so that they only use `id`, so a `Foo` instance and its string `id` are mapped to the same hashtable bucket.  However say there is a dict with keys being `Foo` instances, and I only have the string `id`.  I want to retrieve the `Foo` instance that the `id` exists in.

One way is to iterate through all keys in the dict, but is there something more efficient/simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve the corresponding `Foo()` object used a key directly, no.

Your options are to loop over all keys and match the `id` attribute, or perhaps *recreate* the object with `Foo(id)`; if all you need to do is use this as a lookup key then that should more than suffice.

If these objects have more attributes and `id` maps uniquely to those attributes, consider adding another dictionary you maintain mapping ids to `Foo()` instances.

Comment: I need to retrieve the same reference of the `Foo` instance stored in the dict, so instantiating a new `Foo` instance is not an option.  I like the idea of having a separate `dict` purely for `id: Foo` mappings.  It sacrifices space efficiency for speed.  Most of the time the code scope will only have knowledge of the string `id` and it needs to modify the corresponding `Foo` instance, so I think I would have to go with the separate dict.

Comment: I realized that my code needed significant refactoring.  The values in the original `dict` should have been instance variables in `Foo`, and the new dict is `id: Foo`.  So my question is moot, but still nice to know that we cannot retrieve a key using a key for dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a *dummy* `Foo` object with the given `id`, and look that up in the map.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Martijn Pieters' answer:

In case your `Foo` is a heavy one, you can define a class `Bar` with minimal functionality (`self.id`, `__eq__` and `__hash__`) and make your `Foo` inherit from it.

Then you can use lightweight `Bar` instance to retrieve value associated with `Foo` object from your dictionary.

Comment: Why not use the string `id` to retrieve the value?  It would be even more lightweight than object `Bar`.  Also I want to use a key to retrieve a key, not a value.  Maybe my situation indicates some problems with my code decomposition.  See my comments to Martjin's answer.

Comment: already seen it (after posting this answer). I would be careful with creating mutable class from string, which is by definition immutable in Python.

Comment: "creating mutable class from string" - what do you mean, and what are the dangers?

Comment: if you inherit from string, your `Foo` will be a string, but at the same it will be mutable. That is just my gut feeling that it is not a good idea, I cannot precisely foresee all implication now, I just see that there might be some. Thus I would rather search for another solution (like storing id as a member), unless I have enough time and Python understanding to analyse this ;o)

Comment: My `Foo` inherits from `object`, not `str`.  The string `id` is already a member variable of `Foo`.